# Gen2 Package, ancestor version creation failing without any code changes for 2GP Managed package

Tags: apex, packaging-2, second-generation-packaging, packaging

I have the following issue with the Second Generation Package, I have this Apex class:

```
global with sharing class TestClass {
    global virtual class B {
    }
    global class C1 extends B {
    }
    global class C2 extends B {
    }
}
```

On the foobarbaz namespace, in a managed package, I upload and release a first managed version (v1.0.0) and then, without changing any code at all, I try to create a new minor version (v1.1.0) that have for ancestor the v1.0.0 but I'm getting the following error when I try to create the version:

> TestClass: Supertype, foobarbaz.TestClass, relationship must be maintained: foobarbaz.TestClass.C1,TestClass: Supertype, foobarbaz.TestClass, relationship must be maintained: foobarbaz.TestClass.C2

I tested creating a minor version without changing the code source with the First Generation Package, and it's working fine.

So, what's the issue there?

Edit:
Here's a Minimium Reproducible Case repository https://github.com/louis-bompart/sturdy-funicular

It's a simple sfdx project setup with sfdx-cli and the aforementioned Apex class.
The first commit is the first release (v1.0.0)
The second commit is the second attempted release. (v1.1.0)

Edit2:
The ancestory tree: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/10bbSnR5wB1mgfuGNJ3fz_YLEYC-ahevnjqbmZyHECDw/edit?usp=sharing
Here's some more elaborated steps on how to reproduce:
After the package is created, but no version exists yet:

- sfdx force:package:version:create -p FooBazBar -v mydevhub@foo.com -x -c
- sfdx force:package:version:promote --package 04tmypackageid -v mydevhub@foo.com
- Update sfdx-project.json by adding "ancestorVersion": "0.1.0.1" in the only packageDirectory
- sfdx force:package:version:create -p FooBazBar -v mydevhub@foo.com -x -c
- Crash

Comment: Could you share the package ancestry for your packages ? Similar to here (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_upgrades.htm)

Comment: It perfectly worked fine for the same code you have. So i am curious how are you creating the packages ? Can you share the commands you executed for this ?

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava, here's the package ancestry tree: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/10bbSnR5wB1mgfuGNJ3fz_YLEYC-ahevnjqbmZyHECDw/edit?usp=sharing  
For the commands I executed, after the package is created, but no version exists yet:  
- sfdx force:package:version:create -p FooBazBar -v mydevhub@foo.com -x -c 
- sfdx force:package:version:promote --package 04tmypackageid -v mydevhub@foo.com  
- Update sfdx-project.json by adding "ancestorVersion": "0.1.0.1" in the only packageDirectory  
- sfdx force:package:version:create -p FooBazBar -v mydevhub@foo.com -x -c  
- Crash.

Comment: Thanks @Louis. I am going to try now with a different namespace.

Comment: (@MohithShrivastava sorry for this poor comment, updated post instead)

Comment: ok i am not able to reproduce it at all. I was able to successfully create packages via CLI. If you want to install it and see the packages follow below links

Comment: https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t3h00000246dyAAA

Comment: https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t3h00000246e3AAA

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava, first thanks for your blazing fast answer, that's really appreciated.
My mistake, I was not clear in my OP. I'll edit it right away. but the main take-away is that I had the issue with a managed package, not an unmanaged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107281/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-louis-bompart).

Comment: This is definitely a bug. I was able to reproduce it with 2GP managed packaging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107321/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-louis-bompart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is been brought to the attention of Salesforce Managed Package team and a bug is raised against this with Internal work item number W-7503352.

Please reference this if you ever raise a support case for this.

There is a known issue created for [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HVUeQAO&title=2gp-managed-package-creation-failed-if-previous-version-has-a-global-class-that-extends-global-virtual-class) now. Please follow for updates.

Comment: I will also keep updating this as i hear more from product teams.